# How to properly use a UIColor as a property

Tags: objective-c, properties, uicolor

Why is my color property always `null`?

```
@interface StreamingMediaControlButton : UIButton

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *color;

@end

@implementation StreamingMediaControlButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        _color = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"color: %@", self.color);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.color.CGColor);
}
@end
```

Comment: How do you know it's always `null`? Also, now is it `color` or `iconColor`?

Comment: Set Break point on initWithFrame and Debug. It should go inside init Method. If its not going inside, your property will always be null.

Comment: Is this button defined in a XIB file?

Comment: synthesize your color object.

Comment: hav you got the solution?

Comment: you need to synthesize it, then you can use it with self

Comment: You don't have to synthesize it since Xcode 4.4

Comment: In 'init' methods you should avoid using getters and setters but assign it to the variable directly using '_color'

Comment: @MikeWeller yes I chose to subclass UIButton instead of UIControl so I can place and size the control in interface builder.

Comment: Then you need to implement initWithCoder: instead.

Comment: @MikeWeller Right. Only now I get "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.". Any ideas why that would mess with the constraints?

Comment: @HAS Right. changed question.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327145/unable-to-simultaneously-satisfy-constraints-no-constraints-in-place) or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169158/unable-to-simultaneously-satisfy-constraints-when-animating) solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your previous comment said you are using interface builder, which means a different init method is invoked on the button. You need to implement:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:decoder])) {
        // setup code
    }

    return self;
}
```

Quite often it's good practice to implement both `initWithCoder:` and `initWithFrame:` and have them both call a `commonInit` method where your shared setup code goes.

Comment: Just the act of implementing initWithCoder seems to call initWithFrame via [super init];

Comment: initWithCoder seems to reset the view's frame property. Is this supposed to happen? The idea is to place and size the objects view in interface builder. This happens even if initWithFrame is not overridden.

Comment: ....that would be because initWithCoder should call [super initWithCoder] not [super init]. Right.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use Color RGB value instead of directly defining color that would be more effective.

Comment: As it will be a reusable interface control, I wanted to stick with UIColors. Ideally the control's color property would be set to a the chosen UIColor, but default to white.